# Add validation on transaction in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a Model named `StudentProductRelationship` with columns `student_id`, `product_id` and `primary_product`. `primary_product` is a boolean field. I want to add a validation on the model such that after every transaction for every `student_id`, atleast one and only one `primary_product` is true. I don't want to change db design for this. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can combine uniqueness validation with scope option - http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#uniqueness

> There is a :scope option that you can use to specify other attributes
>   that are used to limit the uniqueness check:

```
class StudentProductRelationship < ActiveRecord::Base   
  validates :primary_product, uniqueness: {scope: :student_id} 
end
```

Together with conditional validation - http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#conditional-validation

```
  class StudentProductRelationship < ActiveRecord::Base   
      validates :primary_product, uniqueness: {scope: :student_id}, if: "primary_product"
  end
```

For checking that at least one "true" is present, you may use [custom validation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#custom-validators), although this really needs to be made wise. Running a verification query for each object is tough. It should probably be done not on a model level (i.e. per object), but somewhere in controller where you do mass updates of your joint objects. Wrap it inside transaction, by the way.

Comment: Thanks bu there is a small catch atleast one and only one `primary_product` is true

Comment: You may use [custom validation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#custom-validators) for checking of at least one "true" presence, although this really needs to be made wise. Running a verification query for each object is tough. It should probably be done not on a model level (i.e. per object), but somewhere where you do mass updates of your joint objects.

Comment: Is there any way we can check `scope` in custom validator method?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Inside custom validation method you can have access to all record fields, including student_id. But again, the more I think about it, you really can't do validation for "at least one" on per-record basis. Assume you update two records for same student, by "moving" primary product flag from first product to second (true-false => false-true). When you update first record, you change true to false - and at this moment you don't have any true values yet. It will only appear when you update second record.

Answer (score 0):

One solution could be add validation in your model `StudentProductRelationship` by simply adding:

```
validates :primary_product, uniqueness: true
```

Comment: `primary_product` is a boolean field. There can be multiple trues

Comment: @utcghghvgh might want to do a migrationg and set `primary_product` default value as `false`, then when you create an instance you can set it to true to a single user you want. hope that helps mate